# Can anyone solve this odd integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can anyone solve this odd integral?

$$\int\frac{e^{-50(\frac 1x-1)^2}}{x}\,dx$$

for $x>0$. I couldn't  . . .

Comment: do you mean this here  ‎$$\int\frac{e^{-50(\frac{1}{x}-1)^2}}}}{x}dx$‎$‎

Comment: $$\int \!{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-50\, \left( {x}^{-1}-1 \right) ^{2}}}}{x}}
\,{\rm d}x$$

Comment: i do not think that there is a solution in the known elementary functions

Comment: A bit of context would not hurt. Where did you find that integral? Are you interested in a elementary primitive (there is none) or in the value of the integral over some interval? What have you attempted?

Answer (score 2):

Integrating over $(0,1)$, and letting $t=\dfrac1x$ , followed by $u=t-1$, we are left with evaluating

$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-au^2}}{u+1}~du~=~\frac{\pi\cdot\text{erfi}\Big(\sqrt a\Big)-\text{Ei}(a)}{2~e^a}~$ for $a=50$, where **erfi** stands for the [imaginary 

 error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), and **Ei** represents the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). $~$ See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the

[Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more information.

Comment: @Maryam: The lower limit is $0$ **after** that substitution.